# Page 1 of ... shows too many total pages

Tags: page-numbering, context

My document has a cover page and a TOC. Page numbers are set up to show `Page 1 of ...`. Context ignores the cover page and sets the title page as page 1 but does include the cover page when calculating the total number of pages of the document. This creates a problem with the last page as it shows `Page n-1 of n`.

How can I correct this problem?

As an aside, I would be interested to know why I have to put `startstandardmakeup` and `stopstandardmakeup` on my cover page to get the graphic to show.

MWE below:

```
% Turn off page numbering as it is set in the footer
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
% Setup headers and footers
\setupfootertexts[][Page \pagenumber{} of \totalnumberofpages]

% Set up Cover Page
\defineoverlay[CoverPage]
              [{\externalfigure[cow][cow]}]

\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]

%start document
\starttext

\setupbackgrounds[page][background={CoverPage,CoverTitle}]

\startstandardmakeup
\stopstandardmakeup

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=]

% Insert TOC
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={chapter,section,subsection},alternative=c]
\completecontent
\page[yes]

%start main part of document
\input ward 

\page[yes]

\startsection[title={Title 1}]
\input ward 
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Title 2}]
\input ward 
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Title 3}]
\input ward 
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Comment: You may want to try `\lastpage`

Comment: As for your question about the title page: you don't have to put the `\startstandarmakeup`, but there has to be something: you put the picture in the background, and if there's nothing in the foreground, TeX simply won't typeset the page. You could simply put the picture in the foreground or have something like `\null\page`, that would have the same effect.

Comment: @Thomas In principle you are right, but the standard makeup also clears the headers and footers as well as inhibits the page counter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you are looking for is: `\currentpage\ of \lastpage`

```
% Turn off page numbering as it is set in the footer
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
% Setup headers and footers
\setupfootertexts[][Page \currentpage\ of \lastpage]

% Set up Cover Page
\defineoverlay[CoverPage]
              [{\externalfigure[cow][cow]}]

\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]

%start document
\starttext

\setupbackgrounds[page][background={CoverPage,CoverTitle}]

\startstandardmakeup
\stopstandardmakeup

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=]

% Insert TOC
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={chapter,section,subsection},alternative=c]
\completecontent
\page[yes]

%start main part of document
\input ward

\page[yes]

\startsection[title={Title 1}]
\input ward
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Title 2}]
\input ward
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Title 3}]
\input ward
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Concerning your aside: `\startstandardmakeup` and `\stopstandardmakeup` insert a new, empty page without footer and header. Which is needed, since you want to include the cover page as background image.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the `userpage` counter, as this will automatically exclude uncounted pages, such as a cover page.  To have the cover page counted either way, just add `pagestate=start` to the standard makeup.

Also, you could make use of structurals such as `\start...\stopfrontmatter` and `\start...\stopbodymatter` instead of manually inserting pagebreaks everywhere.  To have an automatic pagebreak before a new section just use

```
\setuphead
  [section]
  [page=yes]
```

This makes the code clearer and most of the comments are now redundant.

```
% Turn off page numbering as it is set in the footer
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
% Setup headers and footers
\setupfootertexts[][Page \userpagenumber\ of \lastuserpagenumber]

% Set up Cover Page
\defineoverlay[CoverPage]
              [{\externalfigure[cow]}]

\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]

\setuphead
  [section]
  [page=yes]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter

  \setupbackgrounds[page][background=CoverPage]
  \startstandardmakeup[pagestate=start]
  \stopstandardmakeup
  \setupbackgrounds[page][background=]

  \setupcombinedlist[content][list={chapter,section,subsection},alternative=c]
  \completecontent

\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter

  \input ward

  \startsection[title={Title 1}]
    \input ward 
  \stopsection

  \startsection[title={Title 2}]
    \input ward 
  \stopsection

  \startsection[title={Title 3}]
    \input ward 
  \stopsection

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```